# Check if the snapshot already Exist in SQL server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, snapshot

I want to check in a database that if it snapshot is already existing. If yes I want to delete the snapshot and create a new one. How can i do it in an efficient manner. Also is it possible to check the time when it was created? I am using C# at back-end to achieve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a SQL query to determine whether a database is a snapshot  and then execute that query from with C#.

This SQL query should help you determine if a database snapshot exists:

```
select *
from sys.databases
where name = '<your_db>'
and source_database_id is not null
```

I would refer to this article for an example of how to execute SQL from within C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx#_SqlClient

The code will likely need elevated privileges within SQL Server in order to execute this query so be careful with how these features are exposed. I strongly suggest using a parameter-based query as shown in the example within that link to avoid exposure to a SQL injection attack.

See this question for more information on how to determine if a database is a snapshot using SQL server: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35105/how-can-i-query-for-existing-database-snapshots-in-sql-server

This article contains information on dropping snapshots from within SQL server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190220.aspx

Similarly, this article indicates how to create one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175876.aspx

Please be careful when dropping snapshots via code. The same permissions used to drop a snapshot allow the user to drop a database.

This article indicates that the date the snapshot was created is stored in the column create_date: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I'd look at the [Database class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.aspx) in the SMO library. Specifically, the `IsDatabseSnapshot` and `DatabaseSnapshotBaseName` properties. If memory serves, `CreateDate` should reflect the creation date of the snapshot, not the source database.